Whats the clinking noise on my car when braking?
When braking my 2017 Honda Accord it makes sort of a clinking sound with every rotation of tire, as the car speed decreases, the sound gets slower, it’s a on and off things, sometimes it doesn’t make a sound, sometimes its horribly loud
I’ve had my car inspected by 2 different mechanics and some of my handy friends, they all have said my brakes are in perfect condition and that my wheel bearings are too, nobody has been able to find the problem besides often telling me they didn’t hear it while driving. Here is a video of the noise: https://youtube.com/shorts/AijEqeqcvOU?si=fpG-0mEq1fm9X_JJ
The noise comes from the front passenger side and drives me nuts. I don’t want to spend hundreds of dollars or waste time just for a mechanic to tell me everything is fine again, please help.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

If you can do so safely: (1) Try shifting to Neutral during an episode of clunky braking, and see if the noise stops or changes. (2) Brake during a left curve in the road and (3) Brake during a right curve in the road. See if the noise is equal or different in left and right curves. We need more info to narrow down the possible causes. You can give the results in a comment or click EDIT under your question to add new info.

It will most likely be a rotor that needs to be machine, then you might want to remove, clean and regrease the slider pins on the caliper. Sound will be there specially when breaking slow and when cold.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
